# Write a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{RP}^2\setminus \{Z=0\}$ in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry

Define as usual $\mathbb{RP}^2:=(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\})/\mathbb{R}^*$ and on $\mathbb{RP}^2\setminus \{X=0\}$ consider this riemannian metric $g=\frac{dX^2+dY^2+dZ^2}{X^2}$ (where $X,Y,Z$ are homogeneous coordinates).

**Question: how is $g$ written in homogeneous coordinates?**

Hwang explained my how to write in homogeneous coordinates the round metric $g_r=\frac{dX^2+dY^2+dZ^2}{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}$ on the whole $\mathbb{RP}^2$, but I can't understand how to apply the reasoning on $g_r$ to $g$. In particular is the decomposition in radial and tangential vector done in the same way? What should I subtract to $\frac{dX^2+dY^2+dZ^2}{X^2}$?

Thank you!

Comment: You are pretty near, but note that your $g$ is undefined on the line $X=0$.

Comment: yes! sorry I mean that $g$ is defined on $\mathbb{RP}^2\setminus \{X=0\}$

Comment: This metric is well-defined on $\{X \neq 0\}$, but it's not the "round" metric coming from the round sphere, since the distance in this metric to the line $\{X = 0\}$ is infinite. (In fact, setting $X = 1$ shows your metric is Euclidean in the affine chart $\{X \neq 0\}$.)

Comment: Thank you, but how can it be written in coordinates $u,v$?

Comment: No longer sure what your question is, but again, your metric $g$ is equal to the Euclidean metric $du^{2} + dv^{2}$ in the affine chart $\{X \neq 0\}$, as can be seen by setting $X = 1$ (so that $dX = 0$). This metric does not extend smoothly over the line $\{X = 0\}$. (If it did, the projective plane would admit a flat metric, which it doesn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$**Hint**: If $\pi:\Reals^{3} \setminus\{(0, 0,0)\} \to \Reals\Proj^{2}$ denotes the projection and if $g$ is the unit round metric on the projective plane, then $\pi^{*}g$ is $O(3)$-invariant, scale-invariant, restricts to the round metric on the unit sphere, and is degenerate along lines through the origin. The symmetric two-tensor
$$
\frac{dX^{2} + dY^{2} + dZ^{2}}{X^{2} + Y^{2} + Z^{2}}
$$
(which is probably what you were trying to write down) is $O(3)$-invariant, scale-invariant, and restricts to the round metric on the unit sphere, but has a non-zero radial component that must be subtracted off:
\begin{align*}
\pi^{*}g
  &= \frac{dX^{2} + dY^{2} + dZ^{2}}{X^{2} + Y^{2} + Z^{2}}
   - \frac{(X\, dX + Y\, dY + Z\, dZ)^{2}}{(X^{2} + Y^{2} + Z^{2})^{2}} \\
  &= \frac{(X^{2} + Y^{2} + Z^{2})(dX^{2} + dY^{2} + dZ^{2}) - (X\, dX + Y\, dY + Z\, dZ)^{2}}{(X^{2} + Y^{2} + Z^{2})^{2}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't get it, my metric has just $X^2$ in the denominator. Also, once I write $\pi^*g$ as you do, how do I write it with respect to $u,v,du,dv$? Does my method seem right to you?

Comment: As noted in my previous comment, the metric $(dX^2 + dY^2 + dZ^2)/X^2$ is not the round metric on the projective plane; my guess is you were aiming for $(dX^2 + dY^2 + dZ^2)/(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)$, but that's not right, either. <> Once you have the correct expression for the pullback, you can set $X = 1$, $(Y, Z) = (u, v)$, and $(dY, dZ) = (du, dv)$.

Comment: ok, but then I don't understand why $\pi^*g$ has a radial component that must be subtracted off and how do I get that it is $\frac{XdX+YdY+ZdZ}{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}$. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: The radial vector $(X, Y, Z)$ at the point $(X, Y, Z)$ has unit length with respect to $(dX^2 + dY^2 + dZ^2)/(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)$. To remove this, compute the orthogonal projection of a vector $(U, V, W)$ onto $(X, Y, Z)$: $$\frac{UX + VY + WZ}{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}(X, Y, Z) = \left(\frac{X\, dX + Y\, dY + Z\, dZ}{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}(U, V, W)\right)(X, Y, Z),$$whose norm-squared is$$\left(\frac{X\, dX + Y\, dY + Z\, dZ}{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}\right)^{2} (U, V, W).$$

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, $\frac{XdX+YdY+ZdZ}{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}$ is a metric on $S^2$ and to pull it back on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ we have to substract this radial term which is lost in the quotient. but then my last question is: which should this term appear with the - sign instead of +?

Comment: Not exactly: Every vector in $\mathbf{R}^3$ decomposes into "radial" and "tangential" components. The metric $g_0 := (dX^2 + dY^2 + dZ^2)/(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)$ does not annihilate radial vectors, so something must be subtracted to cancel the radial component. The one-tensor $(X\,dX + Y\,dY + Z\,dZ)/(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)$ gives the radial component of a tangent vector; its square gives the norm-squared of the radial component. Subtracting the square gives a positive semi-definite symmetric two-tensor that annihilates radial vectors.